# Why "isContentEditable" is always false in chrome browser whereas IE its working fine?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am checking the event's `keyCode` for backspace:

```
var element = document.activeElement;
if (!element.isContentEditable){
    if (event.keyCode == 8) { 
        return false; 
    }
```

This works fine with IE, but not with chrome as `isContentEditable` is always return false.
anyone knows the answer, why?

Comment: If the element is hidden, chrome will return false

Comment: it's a [reported issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313082)

Comment: Its not a hidden element. I am using it for login dialog , where i have 2 text-boxes for username and pasword.